# How to remove an e4crypt key?

Tags: linux, encryption, ext4

I want to encrypt a folder on an ext4 file system. This is how I have set up the encryption:

```
[root@test /]# e4crypt add_key
Enter passphrase (echo disabled): 
Added key with descriptor [5f23c1bfa081cfc5]
[root@test /]# mkdir /test
[root@test /]# e4crypt set_policy 5f23c1bfa081cfc5 /test
Key with descriptor [5f23c1bfa081cfc5] applied to /test.
```

I can now create and access files in `/test`. The key also shows up in `keyctl`:

```
[root@test /]# keyctl show
Session Keyring
 802247658 --alswrv      0     0  keyring: _ses
 961235403 --alsw-v      0     0   \_ logon: ext4:5f23c1bfa081cfc5
```

How can I remove this key again, in order to make the encrypted directory inaccessible?

Both `e4crypt new_session` and `keyctl unlink 961235403` removed the key from `keyctl`, but the directory remains accessible.

Answer (score 1):

I think the system cache holds the contents of directories and files you have previously read in memory and that's why you can still see the contents after unlinking the key.

If you clear the pagecache, dentries and inodes using:

```sh
sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Then you won't be able to see the contents.

I also read that if you remount the filesystem it should do the same.

Comment: Please [edit] and add info to the answer and not in the comments